# how to check 200 ok using Bunit in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: unit-testing, moq, xunit, blazor-webassembly, bunit

I am new to Blazor WebAssembly  and unit testing.

I want to do a unit test

1. Check whether a API returns with status code 200?
2. Check whether the API return correct output

How can I do both?

I tried like this

```
    public class CreateParticipantApiTest : TestContext
    {

        [Fact]
        public void ListAllAsyncShouldReturn200Status ()
        {
                var cut = RenderComponent<ParticipantsGetAll>(); // I face error at this line

//removed rest
        }

    }
```

```
public class ParticipantsGetAll : IEndpoint<IResult, GetAllParticipantsRequest>
{
// removed
}
```

Error :
CS0311  The type 'ParticipantEndpoints.ParticipantsGetAll' cannot be used as type parameter 'TComponent' in the generic type or method 'TestContext.RenderComponent(params ComponentParameter[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ParticipantEndpoints.ParticipantsGetAll' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.IComponent'.    test    Test\Participant\CreateParticipantApiTest.cs    27  Active

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `RenderComponent` method to render something that is not a component. Your `ParticipantsGetAll` type is not a component. Learn more at https://bunit.dev/docs/getting-started/writing-tests

Just test your class `ParticipantsGetAll` like you would normally in C#. There is nothing Blazor specific about that.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I am new to unit testing too. I am asking How can I do unit test for ListAllAsyncShouldReturn200Status. I mean How can check an API return status code 200 not not in unit testing. Instead of `ParticipantsGetAll` I should use a component. But I want to do test for endpoint status

Comment: Hi Egil, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74828550/can-we-do-unit-testing-controllers-in-blazor-webassembly-using-bunit This is another question from me. Can you guide me?

Comment: Microsoft has a lot of good docs and learning sessions on testing in .net. start with the basics, like testing a simple class library, and take it from there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2022