# Can we do unit testing controllers in Blazor WebAssembly using Bunit

Tags: unit-testing, blazor, xunit, blazor-webassembly, bunit

Can we do unit testing for controllers/end point in Blazor WebAssembly using Bunit x unit?

https://bunit.dev/

like this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api?

If not what is the way to do unit test for API status code checking in Blazor WebAssembly?

Please guide me.